# SQLite - Extract substring between delimiters for REPLACE function

Tags: sqlite, replace, trim, substr, ogr

I have a column field: `location`.  I need to extract the string between the first and second delimeter *('/')*.

I already have a column `name` where I `ltrim` to the first `'/'`.  I've tried to create a similar query with a combination of `rtrim`, `replace`, `substr` as my `source` column to no avail.  Here is what my data looks like.  I want to extract `AML`, for example.  Right now, there are only three options (*value1*, *value2*, *value3*) between the first and second delimiters, but there could be more later.

```
Attribute data
----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Field    | First value
----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 location | './AML/Counties/*****************kyaml_20190416_transparent_mosaic_group1.tif'
 name     | 'kyaml_20190416_transparent_mosaic_group1.tif'
----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What is the best way of creating my column `source` with the value from `location`?

Output should be like this:

```
Attribute data
----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Field    | First value
----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 location | './AML/Counties/****************kyaml_20190416_transparent_mosaic_group1.tif'
 name     | 'kyaml_20190416_transparent_mosaic_group1.tif'
 source   | 'AML'
----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

With [`substr()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) and [`instr()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr):

```
select *,
  substr(
    substr(location, instr(location, '/') + 1),
    1,  
    instr(substr(location, instr(location, '/') + 1), '/') - 1
  ) as source
from data
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9guR2hXCbwDK3dbVLMAzGA/0).

Comment: My first step in the project is to create a shapefile (could be JSON) index from a list of files in a csv.  The output only has the geometry and the `location` field.  I use `ogrinfo box_tiles.shp -sql "ALTER TABLE ADD name character(100)`, same for `source character(20)"`.  Your method might work better because the the only fields I really want are `name` and `source`.  I could use `ogr2ogr` with your `select` statement to incorporate both `subtr ...` to create my two fields.  Only difference is this creates a new file instead of editing one.  Both ways work.

Comment: Strange that no one seems to need this. I tend to look at data in large Excel spreadsheets through “SQLite glasses” to catch careless errors. Today I was investigating the suspicion that a `0` had been forgotten when I stumbled across a representative of `24.%d` under masses of `240.%d`. I wanted to be able to quantify this, and I was able to thanks to your solution! I hope it gets more attention in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I used [forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10498828/forpasforks) query to modify my query.  Here is my final query

```
ogrinfo box_tiles.shp -dialect SQLITE -sql \
 "UPDATE box_tiles SET source = \
  substr(\
    substr(location, instr(location, '/') + 1), 1, \
    instr(substr(location, instr(location, '/') + 1), '/') - 1)"
```